# Web Browser control not showing HTMLTable cell borders

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, html-table

I have this weired problem using `webBrowserControl` in C# (tested with both
VS 2005 and VS 2012 as I thought the later version will work but it did not).

I have a web page (asp.net) in which I am manually generating some
HTMLtables, it works fine, for some reasons I want to shift the page to
Win Forms application (a button click on the form will load the URL i.e. the local
host aspx page, inside the web browser control on the form)

But when the tables are displayed in the web browser, they miss some cell's borders
i dont know why is this happening, it is a simple HTML table, and I have not
used any fancy styling over it, just simple tables with `<td>` borders set to 1 px.

So the problem is, the web page displays perfectly, in all browsres (IE, FF, Chrome)
But inside the webBrowser control it hides borders for some cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooooh
I solved it, it might be effective for other people so I am sharing it.

In fact I was filling out the table cells with `.InnerText = " ";` value i.e. a single space, I change it to: `.InnerHtml = "&nbsp";` and it works fine now

So the real issue was, in the win forms application, the web browser was
hiding the cell borders that have empty space in them, interesting to know
this as webbrowser itself uses IE basis etc

Answer (score 0):

These are the image: first is for webbrowser control[image]

[image]